# stylesheet styling not applying to one specific

Tags: html, reactjs, css

I'm working within a React app and have a component that renders numerous `span` tags.  The tags all have different class names and receive all their styling from the linked stylesheet.  Except for one class, which is shown below as `actions`.  For some reason, I cannot figure out how to update this one class via the stylesheet.

If I go into Chrome Dev tools and change the styling to the `actions`, the changes will render.  If I create a `customStyle` object in the component and apply `actions` with a `style` attribute pointing to that object, the class will then style as expected.

However, if I add an ID to the `actions` span tag and try to style from the linked stylesheet, the issue comes back and none of my custom styling is applied to `actions`.  I've tried removing all the styling for the `actions` class and only rendering a `background-color` of `red`, but even that won't take.

Is there some reason I may be missing that allows all other classes in this component to be styled via the stylesheet, but `actions` cannot?

Thanks in advance for any responses, and please let me know if there's any more additional info I can provide.

Below is component code:

```
import React from 'react';

const ListHeaderComponent = (props) => {  
  return (
    <span className='header'>
      <span className='subheader'}>
        <span className='content'>
          Hello
        </span>
      </span>
      <span className='subcontent'>
        This is where the content goes
      </span>
      <span className='actions' id="what">
        This is where the actions go
      </span>
    </span>
  );
};

export default SplitViewListHeader;
```

I have gone through the stylesheet thoroughly and the class is only referenced once.  Below is a sample of code that won't take that I've tried with the class that doesn't update:

```
.actions {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: There might be several reasons. Can you please share the impacted component code and stylesheet as well. So that it will help readers to help you with the best possible solution

Comment: i've updated with component code and further details about styling.  Let me know if there's anyhting else i can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS scripts when pointed towards an element id is very particular about it. It will only point to that very element and have no effect on the nested sequence. That is why they are only used to point towards very specific elements that have standalone functions; or just use a name. I think that is the reason why id won't work.

Comment: Right, and I agree with that.  I had try to style it using an ID just to see if it would take before making this post, and I just haven't removed the ID yet.  I typically reference the class name in the stylesheet, it's just this one class that doesn't like the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use class="" instead of className=""?

Comment: I haven't tested this out yet, but since `className` is used and works properly in all other cases besides `actions` I'm not super confident it will resolve the issue.  I'm going to test when I get back to my computer and will let you know if that does the trick!